# What is the dependency for "Activator"?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Following code "Activator" showing error. Can you please share your ideas how to solve this issue.

```
Action actionRefreshTreeViewer = new Action("Referesh"){
....
....
actionRefresh.setImageDescriptor(Activator.getImageDescriptor("/icons/download.png"));
```

Comment: Show us the Import Statement for Activator please.

Comment: An activator is a class you may, or may not, have in your plugin. What the class is called depends on what you said when you created the plugin. Show us your plugin MANIFEST.MF, and clarify where you got this code from if you don't understand it.

Comment: @vsminkov There are dozens of classes called `Activator` in Eclipse, this is very unlikely to be the correct one.

Comment: @greg-449 yeah, thanks. I deleted my comment